# Why no shell expansion?

Tags: command-line, bash

Why might bash not expand `*`? I want to remove all the `sites-*` files except for the last one, but I would like to test the expansion before running the command and `rm` lacks a `--dry-run` option:

```
$ ls -la
total 1856
drwxr-xr-x  4 dotancohen dotancohen  12288 Jun 11 13:33 .
drwxrwxr-x 28 dotancohen dotancohen   4096 Jun  6 18:04 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   3072 Jun 10 15:07 sites-1402402025.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   7168 Jun 10 15:08 sites-1402402111.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen  12288 Jun 10 15:13 sites-1402402393.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   9216 Jun 10 15:15 sites-1402402493.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   9216 Jun 10 15:16 sites-1402402540.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen 592896 Jun 10 15:48 sites-1402403316.sqlite3

$ ls sites-1402402402*
ls: cannot access sites-1402402402*: No such file or directory

$ echo rm sites-1402402402*
rm sites-1402402402*

$ echo sites-1402402402*
sites-1402402402*

$ find sites-1402402402\*
find: `sites-1402402402*': No such file or directory
```

I know that I could use the `-i` option with `yes no` piped to it, but I would like to diagnose this expansion problem. I don't have any unusual Bash configurations, though I cannot simple disable `.bashrc` for unrelated reasons right now. Therefore, I ask **what might prevent Bash from performing shell expansion**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command(`ls sites-1402402402*`) is wrong.

The correct one is,

```
ls sites-140240*
```

OR

```
ls sites-14024020*
```

When you run this command `ls sites-1402402402*`, `ls` command try to search for the filenames which must have `sites-1402402402` in their names. But this one doesn't really appears in your filenames. So it produces no such file or directory error. But if you run `ls sites-140240*` command, `ls` will list all the file-names starts with `sites-140240`(*The * character serves as a "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing*).